# Fetching data from JupyterLab to tornado server blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, cors, tornado, jupyter-lab

My goal is to develop a JupyterLab extension and clicking on a button from the context menu (right click on a file) would try to fetch json data from a web server by using the Javascript FETCH API.
I am hosting a local tornado server on port 8889 whose *get* and *options* methods' headers are set so that CORS is enabled :

```
def get(self):
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
    ....
    self.set_status(200)
    self.finish(json.dumps(....))

def options(self):
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
    self.set_status(204)
    self.finish()
```

The JupyterLab session is launched on port 8888.
The request is the following :

```
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8889/api/", {
   method: 'GET', 
   mode: 'cors', 
   headers: {
      'Accept: 'application/json'
   });
```

When clicking on the button, the console says that the request is blocked by CORS policy because it cannot find the response header allowing CORS. However, accessing the URL of the tornado endpoint directly correctly shows the response headers as well as the content.
I don't really understand why, is it because I am trying to fetch from JupyterLab?

Comment: Please add the exact error message.  I think you have a preflight response header issue, but your error message would say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

> the console says that the request is blocked by CORS policy because it cannot find the response header allowing CORS.

Quote the *full* error message.

It is going to say the problem is with the **preflight** request.

The preflight request is an OPTIONS request and your OPTIONS end point is not setting the CORS headers.

You shouldn't be making a preflight request though. You said:

> ```
> 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
> ```

… which triggers a preflight but is a lie. You are making a GET request. There is no request body, let alone one written in JSON.

Remove that header.